# "rails g devise install" instead of "rails g devise:install" in rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In my newly created Rails 4 app, I suddenly hit `rails g devise install` instead of `rails g devise:install`. After this mistake, devise components for `install` are generated as I understood from this output:

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20130921224627_devise_create_installs.rb
  create    app/models/install.rb
  insert    app/models/install.rb
   route  devise_for :installs
```

When I try to roll it back like `rails d migration install`, it failed because of not being set `config.secret_key` in `devise.rb`, but there was no file named it, too. I can't run `rails g devise:install` even creating `devise.rb` file and adding secret key configuration. After this process, here's another error occured:

```
    /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `rescue in execute_if_updated': Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x007f6c66a67848 @paths=["/home/ekrem/workspace/contactman4/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007f6c66ac1c80>]> (RuntimeError)
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /home/ekrem/workspace/contactman4/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
        from /home/ekrem/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How can I correct this mistake?

Comment: Well if its "newly" created why don't you just create a new app :)

Comment: It's simplest one, but I'd like to discover detour of this way :)

Comment: generally if you do `rails d generator_name params` (in your case `rails d devise install` it should revert back whatever you just generated for you. Either way, you should be able to fix your problem by removing the line `devise_for :installs` line from your `routes.rb`

Comment: @j03w It worked for me, removing `devise_for :installs` line help me to get rid of errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There're  couple ways around that, but I prefer to just remove everything that generator created.

- the migration
- the model
- the route

I don't see you running the `rake db:migrate` command, so the migration might not be commited. If it is , run `rake db:rollback` wich will rollback the last migration.

One last thought for you. You should really learn how to use Git (or any other VCS you prefer). 'Cause it's exactly on of the problems that a VCS is designed to solve.